# Angular 2 nested views without AUX URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I trying Angular 2 Routing.

My application has 4 pages and 4 routes (r1, r2, r3, r4). I want to separate the two groups of these pages. The "content 1" field for r1 and r2 will be the same. For r3 and r4, the "Content 1" field will be the same and the "Content 2" field will change for each route.

I can do this by calling the Component in the Template, but the "Content 1" field is being recompiled.

I do not want to use AUX routing. The URL looks ugly.

I could have done this before in Angular 1. How can I do that in Angular 2?

[image: example image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with by naming router-outlet as follows.

Assuming you are loading appComponent first,

**app.component.html**

```
<header></header>
<router-outlet name='content1_r1_r2'><router-outlet/>
<router-outlet name='content1_r3_r4'><router-outlet/>
<router-outlet name='content2'><router-outlet/>
<footer></footer>
```

configure your router as follows:

```
{
    path: 'r1', 
    component: 'appComponent',
    children: [
        { path: '', component: contentr12Component, outlet: 'content1_r1_r2' },
        { path: '', component: contentr1Component, outlet: 'content2' }
    ]
}
// write same for r2 just change content1Component you want to load on /r2 route.

{
    path: 'r3',
    component: 'appComponent',
    children: [
        { path: '', component: contentr34Component, outlet: 'content1_r2_r4' },
        { path: '', component: contentr3Component, outlet: 'content2' }
    ]
}

// write same for r4 just change content3Component you want to load on /r4 route.
```

In the above code contentr12Component will remain same for r1 and r2 route, contentr34Component will remain same for r3 and r4. you can replace names as per your component.

This will avoid ugly looking URL as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could create something like this by making each content block a separate component and in your App route place the following:

```
<header></header>
<content-1></content-1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

Now configure the router that it shows the correct `content 2` data for the specific route. Components are also able to communicate so you should be able to pass relevant data to the `content-1` component (see [Component interaction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) in the Angular docs).

Comment: "Content 1" needs to be in a variable structure. R1 and r2 must be `<p> content </p>`, and r3 and r4 must be `<section> content </section>`. So I have to write it into the router-outlet. I can do this with AUX routing, but as I wrote above, the URL looks very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like angular 2 default router does not **really** support multiple named views. This strange AUX routing (named outlets) feature might be useful in some rare cases (popups, dynamic areas etc) but it's absolutely unusable for classic master-child templates with multiple placeholders.

A radical solution could be switching to [ui-router for angular-2](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/) instead of the default one.